# When do you expect to hear back from NSF (DMS)?

Tags: funding

It's nearing a six-month mark since I've submitted my proposal, and I haven't heard anything from them. Does this mean that I'm probably not getting the grant? When do people expect to hear back? There seems to be almost no resources online in this, which I find to be surprising.

Comment: I asked my postdoc advisor the same question today -- also waiting on DMS, for the Algebra & Number Theory grant.  He says he is pretty sure both some acceptances and some rejections have gone out already this year.  If you haven't heard, you're in the middle-ranked category, and how many more are approved depends on funding levels at the NSF.  Sometimes the decisions come as late as July. (Posting as comment, not answer since this is all second-hand, and it's my first time applying.)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in the same category, but I guess things work pretty much the same. Did you by any chance ask your advisor how many people get put in the middle category, and what the rate of success might be, if you're in the middle?

Comment: Asked, but didn't get anything much more specific, I fear.

Comment: This probably isn't what happened, but you should check your spam folders. NSF servers are set up strangely, and the content of grant award letters is similar to certain scams, so they get sent to spam disproportionately often. I went 5 months without learning that my grant proposal had been successful, because the emails from DMS kept going to spam. (I suggest that everyone set up a whitelist filter so that e-mails from nsf.gov are never sent to spam.)

Comment: Nothing in the spam folder. I logged onto fastlane and my proposal still appears as "pending" as well.

Comment: As a general rule with NSF, no news is good news.

Comment: I've heard of decisions from NSF-DMS coming as late as August in recent years.

Comment: Two months later and still no news -- any idea how things look this year?

Comment: I found this blog post to be extremely helpful when applying for my first NSF grant: https://galoisrepresentations.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/applying-for-an-nsf-grant/ it specifically addresses the timeframe for a response.

Comment: @AruRay The blog talks about January/May time-frame, but doesn't mention what is the submission date. Do you know what submission deadline is he talking about ?

Comment: @mystupid_acct I believe mid-October.

Answer (score 4):

The time to hear back on an NSF application is highly variable, both by grant vehicle and for individual applications.  Since most NSF grants are peer reviewed by a panel of academics who also have to meet in person, there's a significant length of time naturally built into the system.

Another part of the delay is that for most programs there are very few applications funded.  As such, even though there may be many clear rejections with relatively fast responses, program managers may end up having a long fight to find sufficient money to accept a project that is right on the boundary of getting accepted.

Still, if you're looking for a number, I have personally never heard of a NSF grant response taking less than 3 months or more than 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there is variability, but [here is an old internal document from NSF](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/papp/gpg_3ex1.pdf) that sets the time at 6 months post submission:

[image]

You can also make a good guess of when your panel met by:

1. Looking up the PO for your proposal in FastLane
2. Going to http://www.nsf.gov/events/advisory.jsp to find their name and associated panel dates. You may need to use the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) to search an earlier version of this page as old panels are periodically pushed off

It occurs to me that an individual with a lot of submissions or an interested group could calculate some useful statistics on this. Just for fun I've [created a Google Form for this](https://goo.gl/forms/h7ZN9ryiGV3gPurJ3). You can edit after submission and see summary charts, etc. It does not collect email addresses or limit to 1 response, so you can use it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god why are you passively living in torment? Get to know the project directors for your grants!!! Rather than being a whiny beggar hoping they fund you, be a human, talking to another human, make a new colleague!

In late August, when the grant agency buildings are so still and quiet you can hear your nerves firing in the stillness, make some appointments by email and go visit relevant project directors.  It will cost you $400 for a plane ticket, a cheap motel, and a few Uber rides.  Sell some plasma as necessary.

Connect by e-mail afterward, and stay memorable. They can help you know up front if your ideas match what is being looked for in the RFP, and their outlook on your general approach is valuable because directors have some veto power over reviewers.  It's okay to approach as a grad student, the granting agencies love fostering student involvement.

I can call and email both my current project directors and they write back same day, one is funded, one is pending. I have spent at least 2 hours in person with each of them. I appreciate their talents and have carefully read their resumes and some of their publishings.

If the delay is driving you mad, then you haven't plugged yourself into the system so you can have a better sense of what's going on and how the schedule work.  Agency project directors are really generally awesome so they are worth getting to know whether or not have a submission that will get funded, and the insights can help make you a better writer for the next round and their journeys to their current role are usually super inspiring!!